# How to open Outlook item with Python

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

I am trying to create a python script to create outlook object to compose emails. I am using the following code.

```
import os
import sys
import win32.client


def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):  
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)

Emailer('hello' , 'Wow it works' , 'hello@test.com')
```

But when I run the script I get an error;

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/cnpanyog/Desktop/Mailtest.py", line 3, in 
>       import win32.client ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.client'

Then tried to search for win32 library by searching for 'win32' and could not find it. Then tried installing 'pypiwin32' and tried importing pypiwin32, then I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/cnpanyog/Desktop/Mailtest.py", line 3, in 
>       import pypiwin32 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypiwin32'

But I had installed it successfully

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
import sys
import win32com.client as win32


def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)

Emailer('hello' , 'Wow it works' , 'hello@test.com')
```

Comment: How can I add an attachment to the e-mail?

Comment: mail.Display(True) blocks the python execution. Is it possible to put it in another thread so it is non-blocking?

Answer (score 0):

If you have several python versions or enviroments installed, verify the version or enviroment that you are using for your script is the same where you are trying to install pypiwin32.